# convert IHtmlHelper<TModel> to IHtmlHelper<dynamic>

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

is possible to convert an instance of object of type
`IHtmlHelper<TModel>` to `IHtmlHelper<dynamic>` or `IHtmlHelper<object>`

or to recreate it as `IHtmlHelper<dynamic>` if convertion is not an option

`htmlObj as IHtmlHelper<dynamic>` works but only when `TModel` is object.

Comment: ...why are you using `dynamic` in the first place?

Comment: @Dai it doesn't have to be `dynamic`, could also be `object`, I just want to use the Html<T> inside a context where I don't want to add the generic type parameter to each class/method where it will be used

Comment: So use the non-generic `IHtmlHelper` interface then. What do you want `Model` for if you don't know its type?

Comment: @Dai it is an option, but it will take a lot of refactoring, and the `T` is needed in certain cases, before calling the context I mentioned that doesn't need the T.

Comment: ...so why can't you make your methods generic too?

Comment: @Dai ended up refactoring to use `IHtmlHelper` and sometimes getting it as generic but always keeping it as `IHtmlHelper`

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea, of course the viewdata of HtmlHelper<TModel> can be repackaged to HtmlHelper<dynamic> through ViewDataDictionary.

Comment: Something like `new HtmlHelper<dynamic>(new ViewContext { ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new HtmlHelper<TModel>(new ViewContext(), new ViewPage()).ViewData)}, new ViewPage());`